# method isInteger(BigDecimal number) isn't compliant with sonar rules

Tags: java

```
 public boolean isInteger(BigDecimal number) {
    boolean ret;
    try {
        number.toBigIntegerExact();
        ret = true;
    } catch (ArithmeticException ex) {
        ret = false;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

This methods is correctly unit tested, but my sonar tells me "Either log or rethrow this exception.". My first reaction is to ignore the sonar rule (they're not mandatory), but I'm not sure if there's a better way to do it without catching an arithmetic exception.

Comment: Why don't you follow Sonar and log the exception?

Comment: Because it's not an exception in my code workflow, it's only a way to check if a bigdecimal is an integer, most of the time it will be logged.

Comment: Ah, you're abusing exceptions. Not a problem, we'll find an alternative for you.

Comment: This has been asked and answered in SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078953/check-if-bigdecimal-is-integer-value

Answer (score 2):

You should ignore the warning. However this warning is not unfounded as exceptions are costly (stack unwinding) and in this case the exception might even happen in maybe 90% of the cases.

So in this case preferably an alternative should be sought:

```
public boolean isInteger(BigDecimal number) {
    return number.stripTrailingZeros().scale() <= 0;
}
```

Here stringTrailingZeros would turn 600.00 into 6E2, hence with scale -2, and 0.0600 would become 6E-2 with scale 2.

Less code, hence even Wally points on the Dilbert scale.

P.S. there exist SuppressWarning annotations for SonarLint, though neat programmer that I am, I do not know the warning key.